# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all' python bet365

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, selector, findall

Hello guys

I was looking for my problem here, but at the moment I did not find a solution.

I am creating to scrape a bet365 website but when I perform the following code, it returns an error:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'

I discovered that table returns an empty value now, but before it did not (1 month ago) I do not know what happened.

The code is this:

```
#firts defined bs4 selectors:

# Data elements bs4 selectors
results_div = {'name': 'div', 'class_': 'ovm-CompetitionList '} 
games_div = {'name': 'div', 'class_': 'ovm-Competition ovm-Competition-open '} 
match_div = {'name': 'div', 'class_': 'ovm-Fixture_Container'} 
competition_div = {'name': 'div', 'class_': 'ovm-CompetitionHeader_Name '}

...

#after def parse_data
def parse_data(driver):
 
    scraped_data = []
    logging.info('Parsing the matches data')
    html = driver.page_source
    soup = bs(html, 'html.parser')
    table = soup.find(**results_div)
    competitions = table.find_all(**games_div)
    for competition in competitions:
        name = competition.find(**competition_div).text
        matches = competition.find_all(**match_div)
        for match in matches:
        ...
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11zRt.png)

Thank you for the attention. Regards!

Answer (score 0):

As in the error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'` which means that the variable 'table' does not scrape anything. it is better to modify

```
competitions = table.find_all(**games_div)
```

to

```
competitions = table.find_all(**games_div) if table else None
```